# Redirecting subdomain to directory on Azure

Tags: azure, iis, dns, azure-web-app-service

Simply put, how can I redirect `test.example.com` to `example.com`? I would like to make the sub-domain seem "real" to the user(redirection in the background, URL is still `test.example.com/index.html`). I have tried modifying my DNS settings on the domain, the IIS configuration, and added my sub-domain to my Azure configuration.

Web.Config

```
<rule name="Push Subdomain to Push folder">
<match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^test.example.com$" />
    </conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://example.com/test/{R:1}" />
```

My DNS Configuration:

Sub-Domain: test | URL: example.azurewebsites.net | Record Type: CNAME (alias)

When I do this, I get this error message:
`The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by changing the above to

```
<rule name="Rewrite sub-domain to dir" enabled="true">
<match url="^(.*)$" />
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^test\.example\.com$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="test/{R:1}" />
```

Comment: A bit old of a post, but I need to ask you. I want to do the exact same thing, on my Azure website. When I did the above, I get an internal server error (500). Can you help me out please? Thanks.